Akshay Venkatesh solution to Problem 2 from IMO 2024
Problem 2 in 2024 IMO is:
For which pairs of positive integers $(a, b)$ is the sequence
$\gcd(a^n + b, b^n + a)$ with $n = 1, 2, \ldots$
eventually constant?
In his talk Akshay Venkatesh outlines the following solution:

Transcript:
My first thought: work modulo primes

Suppose $(a, b) \neq (1, 1)$. We want to show that $\text{gcd}(a^n + b, b^n + a)$ isn’t constant. Let’s look at when a fixed odd prime $p$ divides it.

$$a^n \equiv -b, \quad b^n \equiv -a \pmod{p}$$ take logarithms to get a quadratic equation for $\log(a)$, $\log(b)$.

Ignoring some exceptional cases, we find this has a unique solution for $n$ whenever $\log(ab) = \log(-1)$, i.e. whenever $ab \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

So, if $ab \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, we find that $p$ divides the gcd for some $n$ and not for other $n$. A bit of fiddling gets to the conclusion.


(End of transcript.)
How can this be made into a proof?
I have managed to use some of the ideas to get a proof (see my own answer below), but without getting a quadratic equation, and while still pulling out the $\log a+ \log b + \log (-1)= 0$ condition mostly out of a hat. Can one follow the outline more closely?

Suppose $a, b$ are as wanted. This means that any prime $p$ divides the gcd either for all large $n$ or for no large $n$. Taking logs (or "indexes") mod p, we I get that $p$ dividing the gcd is equivalent to
$$n \log a = \log (-1) + \log b \mod (p-1)$$
$$n \log b = \log (-1) + \log a \mod (p-1)$$
This is equivalent to
$$ (n+1) \log a = (n+1) \log b = \log (-1) + \log b + \log a \mod (p-1)$$
If $\log (-1) + \log b + \log a = 0 \mod (p-1)$ (and since $2 \log (-1) = \log 1 = 0$ this is the same as  $ab = -1 \mod p$ ) then we have
$$ (n+1) \log a = (n+1) \log b = 0 \mod (p-1)$$
For $p>2$, since at least of $\log a, \log b$ is not zero, this holds precisely when $(n+1)=k \mod (p-1)$ for some, but not all values of $k$. This is a contradiction; so there must be no odd primes dividing $ab+1$. This means $ab+1$ is a power of 2. In particular, $a, b$ are odd. If $4$ divides $ab+1$ we can repeat the above argument mod $4$ (since $a$ and $b$ are odd logs make sense etc.), or, in elementary terms, compute mod 4 -- we have ${a, b} ={1, -1}$ so that that for odd $n$ we have $b^n+a=a^n+b=a+b =0 \mod 4$ and the gcd is divisible by 4; and for even $n$ we have $a^n+b= 1+b \mod 4$ and $b^n+a= 1+a \mod 4$ and one of those is not 0, so the gcd is 2. We conclude $ab+1=2$, $a=b=1$.
